# nodejs unable to pass more than one arguments to the script with spawn

Tags: python, node.js

I try to launch a python script with spawn, without argument it is working :

```
toExecute="myscript.py";
const ls = spawn('python',toExecute);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      ...
    });
```

But when I try to pass **other arguments**, its not working anymore :

```
const ls = spawn('python',[toExecute, "test"]);
```

I get following error :

```
 [red] Uncaught Exception: 4 Aug 13:40:59 - SyntaxError: Unexpected
 token u
     at Object.parse (native)
     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/....js:29:20)
     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
     at Pipe.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Comment: The error being thrown suggests that you're trying to parse invalid JSON. Be aware that the `data` event handler may get called _several_ times, and that the data is presented in chunks.

Comment: Many thanks you were right... I was searching the problem somewhere else...
I added the "-u" option to python, and now it is working...